# warehouse management class code

Tags: php, object-oriented, pdo

I'm writing a simple class to manage a warehouse, so it's supposed that it will use a database connection. 
All works fine for now, and I'm actually working to finish the UI. 
Since I think to be a newbie in PHP OOP, I would appreciate much if anyone can review my code to help me improving it.

Here is the class code:

```
class market{

private $db;
private $stmt;    

private function database(){

if($this->db === null){        
$this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=marymarket','root','root');   
    }
return $this->db;    
}    
 /* I need to pass an array with arguments,any help will be appreciated */      
public function insert_article($barcode,$code,$qty,$brand,$article_name,$price,$article_type,$promo_stats,$note){

$stmt = $this->database()->prepare('INSERT INTO products (barcode,code,qty,brand,article_name,price,article_type, promo_stats,note) VALUES (:barcode,:code,:qty,:brand,:article_name,:price,:article_type,:promo_stats,:note)');    
$stmt->bindParam(':barcode',$barcode,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':code',$code,PDO::PARAM_INT);    
$stmt->bindParam(':qty',$qty,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':brand',$brand,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':article_name',$article_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':price',$price,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':article_type',$article_type,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':promo_stats',$promo_stats,PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':note',$note,PDO::PARAM_STR);

if($stmt->execute()){    
echo 'ok';    
} else {
echo 'error';    
}    

}
// this part is commented because i will implement it after the UI will be ready.
//public function insert_supplier(){

//$stmt = $this->database()->prepare('INSERT INTO suppliers (code,supplier_name,iva,tel,fax,email,address,city,cap) VALUES ()');   
//
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//    
//$stmt->execute();    
//   
//}

//private function insert_brand(){
//$stmt = $this->database()->prepare('INSERT INTO brands () VALUES ()');   
//
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$stmt->bindParam(':',PDO::PARAM_STR);
//    
//$stmt->execute();    
//   
//}    
// TO DO    
#public function mod_article(){}
// TO DO        
#public function del_article(){}    

public function list_articles(){

$stmt = $this->database()->query('SELECT * FROM products'); 
foreach($stmt as $result):    

echo '<tr><td id="list-tbl-label">'.$result['barcode'].'</td>';
echo '<td id="list-tbl-label">'.$result['article_code'].'</td>';
echo '<td id="list-tbl-label">'.$result['brand'].'</td>';   
echo '<td id="list-tbl-label">'.$result['article_name'].'</td>';
echo '<td id="list-tbl-label">'.$result['price'].'</td>';   
echo '<td id="list-tbl-label">'.$result['article_type'].'</td></tr>';   
#echo    
endforeach;    
}

public function search($q){

$stmt = $this->database()->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE article_name LIKE :q OR brand LIKE :q OR article_code LIKE :q');    
$stmt->bindParam(':q',$q,PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->execute();    
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();    
foreach($results as $result):
echo '<table class="table table-bordered" id="">  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">INT. CODE</th>
      <th scope="col">BARCODE</th>
      <th scope="col">QTY</th>
      <th scope="col">BRAND</th>
      <th scope="col">PRODUCT NAME</th>
      <th scope="col">PRICE</th>
      <th scope="col">SUPPLIER</th>
    </tr>
  </thead><tbody>';    
echo '<tr><td>'.$result['article_barcode'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$result['article_code'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$result['brand'].'</td>';   
echo '<td>'.$result['article_name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$result['price'].'</td>';   
echo '<td>'.$result['article_type'].'</td></tr></tbody></table>';    
endforeach;
    }
else {
    return false;  
    }    
} 

}
```

Since I don't like to write directly PHP code on my html pages, I also wrote a controller that is called by AJAX. It's supposed that will manage all the necessary operations made by the user who post or need to get data.
Here is the controller code:

```
require_once 'core.php';

$core = new market();

if(isset($_POST['code'] )){

$code = filter_var($_POST['code'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
# $barcode = filter_var($_POST['barcode'],FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);    
$qty = filter_var($_POST['quantity'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

$brand = filter_var($_POST['brand'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$article_name = filter_var($_POST['artName'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
$price = filter_var($_POST['price'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$article_type = filter_var($_POST['artType'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$note = filter_var($_POST['note'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    

$save = $core->insert_article($code,$qty,$brand,$article_name,$price,$article_type,$note);    
if($save){
echo 'ok';    
} else {
echo 'error';    
}

}

if(isset($_POST['q'])){
$q = filter_var($_POST['q'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$results = $core->search($q);    
echo $results;
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger ok, sorry I will not doing this anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry but I have to start with the obvious: your indentation is barely non-existing, making your code needlessly harder to read.

Indentation is important (but not mandatory)!

---

Your use of `filter_var(..., FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` seems kinda shady.
Perhaps you're trying to remove tags?

This causes huge usability issues, like, not being able to have a `<` symbol anywhere, which can be fixed by using the [function `htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

If you try running:

```
$string = 'I <3 PHP';

echo filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), PHP_EOL;
echo strip_tags($string), PHP_EOL;
echo htmlentities($string);
```

You will see that both `filter_var` and `strip_tags` remove the heart.

---

Your `insert_article()` method seems kinda shady, and your class does way too many things: connect to the database, deal with articles, suppliers and whatnot.

And if I do **anything**, a new PDO is created?

Instead of:

```
private function database(){

if($this->db === null){        
$this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=marymarket','root','root');   
    }
return $this->db;    
}
```

Just do:

```
public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db){
    $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db, $username, $password);
}
```

And pass the values you want like this:

```
$market = new market('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'marymarket');
```

Figuring a way to pass the character encoding is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

**Nitpick time!**

- If you're going to have multiple lines commented, use `/* ... */` instead of `//` or `#`.
- To make the name stand out of a function, you should Capitalize The First Letter (`market` -> `Market`).
- Instead of a function that takes 300 arguments, make it receive an array.
- Instead of echoing `ok`, `error` or a dump of the HTML.
  Send a json code with the result.
  Better yet: make each method return an array with the answer, and do `echo json_encode(...);` with the returned array.
- The alternative syntax is meant to be used for templating (and looks ugly). Use brackets instead, like how you're using on your `if()`s.
- `private $stmt;` is unused. Remove it.
- If you intend to run the `insert_article()` more than once, store the prepared statement into a `static $stmt`, making sure to free the result.
  If you run only once, skip using prepared statements.
- If you're going to have an `else { return false; }`, make it the first thing (Good read: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've read about the `__construct()` that can be useful to initialize the PDO driver, and I've modified that to reflect this things. I will modify the class as you suggested. I'm now working to give to the controller the response in a json format and then visualize it using Jquery `$.each()` . About the `insert_article()` method, I assume that it will run more than one time when the database is compiled the first time, but it will be used only to add new products available in the warehouse, so I will consider to modify it to remove the prepared statements.

Comment: for the `filter_var` instead, I was worried about security of the queries, so I've used it to sanitize all inputs. I know that the final client will never use expression like an heart, so I think it will fit perfectly to prevent an SQL Injection attack. I will consider to use `htmlentities` instead of filter var, but the final target of the webapp will be the supermarket manager who doesn't consider to use charatcers like  the heart you have used as an example.

Comment: `I was worried about security of the queries` <-- NO!!!!! `filter_var` does **NOT** do **ANYTHING** against sql injection attacks. In fact, it is a nice attack vector. Just add a quote that matches the query and everything falls appart. `filter_var` and `htmlentities` are used to clean up the string to present later. Prepared statements are what make your code resistent to sql injection attacks. And if you're running it multiple times, use a static variable. This gives the beneficts of a prepared statement without you having to have a variable for the whole class.

Comment: Ok, so, as you suggested, to improve the code the `$stmt` variable I'm using to do all the operations with the sql queries need to be static. If you can give me an example I will appreciate it much but I've understood the concept. I've edited the code in the question to reflect the actual changes status.  Perhaps the only one problem now is how to render a table using `$.each()` and `JSON.parse`, but this is only because I don't like much to use javascript or jquery for some data rendering operations.

Comment: Please, do not touch the code in the question! Just post a follow-up question whenever you think it is ready, with a link to this question. Also, what I meant with `$stmt` being static is to simply add the `static` keyword before the variable. Literally that. Easier than making a pie or scrambled eggs. This is completely outside the scope of this question, but, instead of `$.each()` and `JSON.parse`, use `for(var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++ )`. Depending on the jQuery version and browsers, use `$.parseJSON`, `JSON.parse` or a library (IE7 and older don't have `JSON.parse`).

Comment: Ok, so I was understand correctly what you mean with `static`. For the code, I've just added a comment about the array as argument of the `insert_article()` function, about this I need to do more research, I've tried to implement it and now I need to debug the code because it's seems that ajax or php itself doesn't save data to the db. I will post the working code soon as i can and i will link to this question.

Comment: If you want, you can try posting to stackoverflow.com, respecting the rules and guidelines of that website.

Comment: @user9741470 While I'm happy to help you and am happy that you accepted my answer, I advise you against it for now. Wait a few days (2-3 days) before accepting an answer. This gives a chance for others and, hopefully, you will find a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Is it strictly necessary for you to define the data type for all fields? With the lack of indentation I find your code quite hard to follow - perhaps something like this would be more readable:

```
// Connect to database

$username = ""; 
$password = ""; 
$host = "";
$dbname = ""; 

try {  
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
} 

catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    die("Failed to connect to database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 


// Insert article

$query_insertArticle = "
    INSERT INTO products
    (barcode, code, qty, brand, article_name, price, article_type, promo_stats, note) 
    VALUES 
    (:barcode, :code, :qty, :brand, :article_name, :price, :article_type, :promo_stats, :note)
";

$query_insertArticle_params = array(
    ':providerID' => $providerID,
    ':barcode' => $barcode,
    ':code' => $code,
    ':qty' => $qty,
    ':brand' => $brand,
    ':article_name' => $article_name,
    ':price' => $price,
    ':article_type' => $article_type,
    ':promo_stats' => $promo_stats,
    ':note' => $note
);

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query_insertArticle);
    $stmt->execute($query_insertArticle_params);
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    die("Failed to insert article: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
```

Your `list_articles()` function is echoing a lot of HTML code unnecessarily. Try to keep all your PHP and HTML seperate. If you are indeed having both PHP and HTML in the same page (not preferable), do something like the following:

```
<?php

$stmt = $this->database()->query('SELECT * FROM products');

foreach($stmt as $result):

?>

<tr>
    <td id="list-tbl-label"><?=$result['barcode'];?></td>
    <td id="list-tbl-label"><?=$result['article_code'];?></td>
    <td id="list-tbl-label"><?=$result['brand'];?></td>
    <td id="list-tbl-label"><?=$result['article_name'];?></td>
    <td id="list-tbl-label"><?=$result['price'];?></td>
    <td id="list-tbl-label"><?=$result['article_price'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php

endforeach;

?>
```

You can do the same with your search results table. Build the table with HTML, and pass the data to it, rather than build the whole thing with PHP echoes.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, this was the first step develop stage of the class.  You can find the final work that i will deploy at this link https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194745/store-and-warehouse-management-class